# listening for page switch events in Eclipse's PageBookView

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to be notified when a PageBookView switches page? I've dug around in the source code a little, but there doesn't seem to be any direct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> When the associated part becomes active, the PageBookView automatically switches to the respective page.

If the PageBookView doesn't offer notifications, you can add a listener to the pages and add a focus listener to their `Control` objects. This should have the same result. (See: [`IPage.getControl()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp))